# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(\pi\sqrt{\cos x})} x$

Tags: calculus, limits

I don't know how can this be solved:
$$
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(\pi\sqrt{\cos x})} x
$$
I've tried to multiply by $\pi\sqrt{\cos x}$:
$$
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(\pi\sqrt{\cos x})}{x\pi\sqrt{\cos x}}
$$

but we have here a hard problem $\lim_{x\to0}(1/x)$.

You think about the limit on the right and on the left but the exercise supposed to be solved by the limit in $0$ and not on the right or the left of it.

Comment: Please, write your question correctly at least.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a formatting guide.

Comment: but how? It's my first time sorry.

Comment: Do you know Taylor expansion ?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the L'Hopital Rule?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe No, all I studied is the continuity of a function. In this exercise we have to determine this limit without using something we haven't studied.

Comment: @player3236 No I've never heard about that. I can't use something I haven't studied in school.

Comment: I have here another exercise like this but they told me to solve it by the compose of two functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that:
$\sin(\alpha)=\sin(\pi-\alpha)$ and

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}x=1\quad\&\quad\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}=\frac12$$

$$\begin{aligned}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\pi\sqrt{\cos(x)})}x&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\pi(1-\sqrt{\cos(x)}))}{\pi(1-\sqrt{\cos(x)})}\frac{(1-\sqrt{\cos(x)})}{x^2}\frac{1+\sqrt{\cos(x)}}{1+\sqrt{\cos(x)}}\pi x\\&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\pi(1-\cos(x)))}{\pi(1-\sqrt{\cos(x)})}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}\frac{\pi x}{1+\sqrt{\cos(x)}}=0\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thank you guys. I got it.

Comment: No problem, Zakaria! (:

Answer (score 3):

Since $\cos x=1-x^2/2+o(x^2)$, we also have
$$
\sqrt{\cos x}=1-\frac{x^2}{4}+o(x^2)
$$
and so your limit can be rewritten as
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(\pi-\pi x^2/4+o(x^2))}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(\pi x^2/4+o(x^2))}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\pi x^2/4+o(x^2)}{x}=0
$$
With $x^2$ at the denominator you'd get $\pi/4$.

A different way to solve the problem is to notice that the given limit is the derivative of $f(x)=\sin(\pi\sqrt{\cos x})$ at $0$; since
$$
f'(x)=\cos(\pi\sqrt{\cos x})\frac{-\pi\sin x}{2\sqrt{\cos x}}
$$
we get $f'(x)=0$

Comment: Starting from the Taylor expansion of $\cos x$, why $\sqrt{\cos x}=1-\frac{x^2}{4}+o(x^2)$?

Comment: @Sebastiano $\sqrt{1+t}=1+t/2+o(t)$

Comment: If $\cos x=1-x^2/2+o(x^2) \implies \sqrt{\cos x}=1-\frac{x^2}{4}+o(x^2)$, yet I have not understood after your comment. Excuse me very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano Use $t=-x^2+o(x^2)$, so $\sqrt{1+t}=1+\frac{1}{2}(-x^2/2+o(x^2))+o(x^2)=1-x^2/4+o(x^2)$

Comment: Ah ok, now I have understood. Thank you very much...again.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for $x\to 0$, $\dfrac {\sin(\pi\sqrt{\cos x})}{\pi\sqrt{\cos x}} \to \dfrac {\sin \pi}{\pi}=0$. The limit for $\dfrac {\sin x}x$ is $1$ for $x \to 0$ only.

Hence we transform the argument of the sine so it tends to $0$, by seeing

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(\pi\sqrt{\cos x})} x = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(\pi - \pi\sqrt{\cos x})} x = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(\pi - \pi\sqrt{\cos x})} {\pi-\pi\sqrt{\cos x}}\cdot \frac {\pi-\pi\sqrt{\cos x}}x$$

Now the first part of the product has limit $1$. Do you know how to calculate the limit of the second part?

Comment: Yes it's easy now. Thank you so mush!

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sin(\pi\sqrt{\cos x})}x=\frac{\sin(\pi(1-\sqrt{\cos x}))}x.$$

As the argument of the sine tends to $0$, we can bypass the sine and evaluate

$$\pi\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\sqrt{\cos x}}x.$$

Now

$$\frac{1-\sqrt{\cos x}}x=\frac{1-\cos x}{(1+\sqrt{\cos x})x}=\frac{2\sin^2\dfrac x2}{(1+\sqrt{\cos x})x}\to0.$$

Comment: I got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*Since you already received good answers for the limit iteself.*

You can go beyond the limit if you compose Taylor series (that is to say working one piece at the time).

$$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
$$\sqrt{\cos(x)}=1-\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x^4}{96}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
$$\pi \sqrt{\cos(x)}=\pi -\frac{\pi  x^2}{4}-\frac{\pi  x^4}{96}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
$$\sin \left(\pi  \sqrt{\cos (x)}\right)= \sin\left(\frac{\pi  x^2}{4}+\frac{\pi  x^4}{96}+O\left(x^6\right) \right)=\frac{\pi  x^2}{4}+\frac{\pi  x^4}{96}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
$$\frac{\sin(\pi\sqrt{\cos (x)})} x=\frac{\pi  x}{4}+\frac{\pi  x^3}{96}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Moreover, this gives a shorcut evaluation of a not so pleasant expression. Suppose $x=\frac \pi{12}$ (this is quite far away from $0$.
The exact expression would be
$$\frac{\sin\left( \pi\sqrt{\frac {\sqrt 6+\sqrt 2} 4}\right)}{\frac \pi {12}} \approx 0.20612 $$ while the above truncated series gives
$$\frac{\pi ^2 \left(3456+\pi ^2\right)}{165888}\approx 0.20620$$